# Why asking password VS Code Remote SSH plugin if I use public key to authenticate?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I just started using Remote - SSH (ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) plugin. I put this code into `settings.json`:

```
    "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
        "myserver": "linux"
    }
```

In the `config` file:

```
Host myhost
  HostName myhost
  User root
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Exactly as the documentation said, and I expected - like in the PuTTY - the plugin just log in and done, but it still asking password for login.

Is there any setting what I missed? Or is there any setting what I must apply to avoid asking password?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the private key as mentioned below.
Additionally, you need to copy the contents of your public key file (the one that ends with .pub), to a file called "authorized_keys", usually located under ~/.ssh

Comment: Different SSH clients and servers use different methods for storing their public and private keys, and whenever I need to set up some client/server pair, I need to find out how/where to store the keys. In this case, connecting a VSCode on a Windows machine to a server on a SLES machine (with the particular SSH server my company uses), this answer's location for the private key on the server was what saved the day. Thanks.

Comment: My public key is already added to authorized_keys, but still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10, if you have stumbled across this issue using the Remote - SSH plugin, run the following in PowerShell (as admin):

```
# Make sure you're running PowerShell as an Administrator
Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service ssh-agent
Get-Service ssh-agent
```

And then if you already generated a key, do `ssh-add`.
It should then prompt you for the passphrase of your key, then you should get a message that your key has been set as the default identity. Open up VSCode and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use the private key, if your public key is  `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` then the private key is probably  `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: I just modified as you suggested, but still asking password.